# VTK vtkDataSet to 3D numpy array and back

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I'm moving my first steps into vtk and I'm quite struggling given the lack of documentation. 
I've got a .vtk file which is a vtkDataSet type object I haven't created. I would need to export the content of it and convert it to a 3D numpy matrix, customise it and its tensor and write everything in a vtkDataSet object and .vtk file.

What I've ended up so far is save the coordinates, which is not what I need, of the points into a numpy array using vtk.util.numpy_support vtk_to_numpy. However, I'd need a 3D numpy matrix representing the volume rendering of it.
Speaking about the tensor, I figured out how and where to save my  9-elements tensor into the file. I'm just not sure on how to set it properly to be related to the points.
The last step, which is 3D numpy array to vtk, looks feasible using numpy.ravel and numpy_to_vtk from vtk.util.numpy_support.
Here's some code I'm using as a test:

```
# reader for mrtrix vtk file
reader = vtk.vtkDataSetReader()
file_name = 'my_file.vtk'
reader.SetFileName(file_name)
reader.Update()

# get the vtkDataArray
data_set = reader.GetOutput()
# these are the coordinates of the points
# I'd need the 3D numpy volume rendering matrix instead
point_array = data_set.GetPoints().GetData()

# test tensor
# I'd need to save a tensor for every element of the 3D numpy matrix
tensor = numpy_to_vtk(np.zeros([data_set.GetNumberOfPoints(), 9]))
tensor.SetName('Tensors_')
point_data = data_set.GetPointData()
point_data.SetAttribute(tensor, 4)
```

Comment: Here is the documentation : 
https://vtk.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be useful in your case:
https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/vedo/examples/volumetric/numpy2volume1.py

and retrieve the numpy object with e.g.

`print('numpy array from Volume:', vol.getPointArray().shape)`

Comment: Thank you mmusy, vtkplotter seems a really useful tool and your code will definitely help. However, unfortunately, I'm still not able to get the volume from the vtkDataSet object. The only thing I got so far is the coordinate array via GetOutput().GetPoints().GetData(). Is there maybe a method to go from coordinate to volume with a user-specified shape?

Comment: You can either:

- reshape the scalars to match the desired numpy grid structure and then use the above example

- create manually a vtkImageData object and then you just use: vol=Volume(img)

- create a new Volume from sparse points like in this example:
https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/blob/master/examples/volumetric/interpolateVolume.py

Comment: You can also try vol=Volume(mydataset) if it is of correct type it should work.

Comment: Thanks mmusy, it works. I also figured out how to keep the relationship between tensors and points by using the point IDs in the cells. Thanks again for your advices.